# $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 , f(x)= (\displaystyle\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} , \displaystyle\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2})$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Be $f(\mathbb{R})$ an application:
$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 , f(x)= \left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} , \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\right).$$
Show that $f$ is an embedding.

I know just the definition: $f$ must be an immersion and the application $f:M \rightarrow f(M)$, where $f(M) \subset N$ is provided with the topology induced by $N$, is a homeomorhpism, but I don't get to prove it.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? If it's the homeomorphism part, why not find an explicit inverse?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I don't know how to verify that $f$ is an immersion and I can't find the inverse of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=f(x')$ then $e^x = e^{x'}$ follows (why?) and so $x=x'$, and hence $f$ is 1-1. Continuity of $f$ is clear. The inverse for a point $(p,q) \in f[\Bbb R]$ isn't hard to find: $\ln(p+q)$ will do, so the inverse is also continuous.

Comment: Okkay, can you also tell me how to verify that $f$ is a immersion?

Comment: @AlbanoPitagorico This shows that $f$ is a differentiable injection with differentiable inverse. What more do you want?

Comment: @AlbanoPitagorico what is your definition of an "immersion"?

Comment: $f$ is an immersion if and only if the derivation of f is injective.